# Регулярка на php

Tags: php

Необходима регулярка на php которая заменяет пустое место после точки на пробел. То бишь 
"Дерево.Листок" заменило на "Дерево. Листок". Спасибо

Comment: Замени точку на точку с пробелом. Регулярка тут не нужна.

Comment: В моём случае нужна именно регулярка.

Comment: `\.` to `\. ` - тоже самое, что без регулярки, только медленно

Comment: «В моём случае нужна именно регулярка» — почему?

Comment: Мы делаем соц. сеть. Замена стоит на  формирование ссылок поста нашего пользователя. На контент постов юзеров прописан модуль с регулярками. Менять точку на точку с пробелом надо для контента постов пользователя, придерживаемся алгоритма, что для постов - регулярки.

Comment: @WildDeveloper ну, я вам написал регулярку :)

Comment: @splash58 вижу, спасибо :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

регулярка, которая не цепляет точки после которых есть пробел

```
<?php
$string = 'Tree.Leaf. Bunny. END';

$pattern = '/(\.)(\S)/';
$replace = '. $2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```